In Python how can I remove a variable number of occurrences of a RegEx pattern from the end of a string?
For this question, assume Proper Name matches this
[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+
Suppose I have a string and it may end like this
sometext  Some Name and in that case we would want to remove the Proper Name.
or it may end like this
sometext Another Namevariation  and that also matches so we move that Proper Name.
or it may end like this
sometext Some Name Another Namevariation  and we would want to remove both names.
Or it may end in digits and then we don't want to do anything.
How to cut off from the string a variable number of occurrences of a Proper Name at the end?

What if you have exactly three words at the end that start with a capital? How will you know that the proper name consists of the last two words, and not the first 2 of those 3?

If you modify your regular expression so that instead of matching a single proper name it matches one or more proper names at the end of a string, like this:
re_proper_name = re.compile(r"( ?[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+)+$")

Then you can simply strip off the portion of a string that matches:
def strip_proper_names(text: str) -> str:
    if mo := re_proper_name.search(text):
        start, end = mo.span()
        text = (text[:start] + text[end:])
    return text

Example usage:
>>> strip_proper_names('sometext Some Name')
'sometext'
>>> strip_proper_names('sometext Some Name Another Namevariation')
'sometext'


@Barmar prefers to use re.sub(). If you were to do that it would look like this:
def strip_proper_names(text: str) -> str:
    return re_proper_name.sub("", text)


Normally we use re.sub() to replace the match with an empty string, not slicing with the span().

Also, since the match is  at the end, text[end:] is guaranteed to be an empty string, so there's no need to add it.
